# Rails - Using mailman to receive emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailman-gem

I'm trying to make an application to receive emails using 'mailman' in RubyonRails3. Can somebody help me provide detail guide on it.

Comment: You need to to provide more information about the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You can see a good tutorial here :

http://dansowter.com/mailman-guide/

or see the README :

https://github.com/titanous/mailman#readme

Comment: To be honest the readme is good but it is unclear as to where the mailman rb files should be located as well as the configuration.
The first link also seems to be dead.